# Vaadin - destroying closed window

Tags: java, memory-leaks, vaadin

I have a Vaadin application that uses multitab approach. `Application.getWindow(String name)` is overriden in the manner that if `super.getWindow(name)` is not found, it creates and adds a new window to an application . All windows have `Window.CloseListener`'s which print message to output. Also I see moments of creation and destroying of windows - constructor and `finalize()` both print messages to console too.

When I refresh same browser tab a new window is created and I see `Window.CloseListener`'s message in console and none of messages from `finalize()` methods. If I add a singleton AtomicLong which counts instances (add in constructor, dec in `finalize()`), I see growing number of instances (on those refreshes) which is not decrementing with time.

It seems like Vaadin stores closed windows somehow. I also `jmap`'ed an application and opened heap file in Eclipse MAT. MAT shows that one of components of closed window, `UriFragmentUtility`, is referenced with a chain: `Application` -> `WebApplicationContext` -> `CommuncationManager` -> (through paintableMap) `UriFragmentUtility` (see image attached).

How can I destroy closed windows to prevent memory leaks?

[image: Eclipse MAT screenshot of path from <code>UriFragmentUtility</code> to GC roots, <code>DofApplication</code> is instance of <code>com.vaadin.Application</code>]

**Update**
I have found that in the code windows are only added to Vaadin `Application` and are not deleted. After adding `Application.removeWindow()` nothing has changed related to refreshing same tab.